# How to display category name of the woocomerce product in wordpress theme header

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

as i mentioned in the title, i want to show the category name & its description in the header file of my theme.

i tried to do with several functions which i got from search like i tried below, i have added this in my functions.php,  but that not works

```
function sk_show_product_category_description() {
if (is_singular( 'product' )) {
    global $post, $product;
    $categ = $product->get_categories();
    $term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );

        echo '<div class="widget-background-wrapper"><div class="widget product-cat-description"><h4 class="widget-title">Note</h4>' . $term->description . '</div></div>';

}
}
```

lastly i tried by including class WC_Product, but that not works too, i have below mentioned the code which i used for it

```
 global $woocommerce, $post, $WC_Product;
 $file =$woocommerce->plugin_path.'/classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php';
$getWooClass = include_once($file);
    $test = $getWooClass->get_categories(122);
var_dump($test);
```

**Please guide how can i display the category name of the current product and & its description??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);

    $count = count($terms); 
    if ($count > 0) {

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<div style="direction:rtl;">';
            echo $term->description;
            echo '</div>';

        }

    }
```

for [more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Hope its helps..